# How to run Karma/Jasmine unit tests with JWPlayer

Tags: unit-testing, jwplayer, karma-runner

I am testing a method, which sets up JWPlayer using the following method

```
jwplayer(playerTag).setup({ [...]
```

When running `Karma` I get an error about `jwplayer` being undefined.

Comment: Is jwPlayer included in the `files` property of your karma configuration?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, got it: `'app/ext_components/jwplayer/Q1zh9uHAEeOVIyIACi0I_Q.js'`. In addition, there a way to invoke jwplayer events from the tests? E.g., `events: {
            onReady: function(event) {
              console.log('jwPlayer: onReady (video event)');
            },`

Comment: My suspicion is that the file is not getting loaded or bootstrapped properly. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with JW player. But it should be defined if you are loading it correctly.

Comment: Do you have an example implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe it's too late, but have you tried to set window.jwplayer as a mock function?

```
window.jwplayer = function() {
        return {
            setup: jasmine.createSpy('jwplayer.setup')
        };
    };
```